# mxml library to parse HTML

Tags: html, c

I wonder is it possible to use embedded library mxml(it deals with XML files) to parse HTML file?
I'm talking about embedded linux cgi application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If page is in `XHTML` format - then possibly yes. But if it is just plain `HTML`, then possibly no - because in html there can be unclosed elements which by definition is malformed xml and thus xml parsers will bark on it.